# How to find path to the package directory when the script is running with `pub run` command

Tags: dart, command-line-interface, dart-pub, dart-io

I am writing a package that loads additional data from the `lib` directory and would like to provide an easy way to load this data with something like this:

```dart
const dataPath = 'mypackage/data/data.json';

initializeMyLibrary(dataPath).then((_) {
  // library is ready
});
```

I've made two separate libraries `browser.dart` and `standalone.dart`, similar to how it is done in the [Intl](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/0.11.9/index.html) package.

It is quite easy to load this data from the "browser" environment, but when it comes to the "standalone" environment, it is not so easy, because of the `pub run` command.

When the script is running with simple `$ dart myscript.dart`, I can find a package path using [dart:io.Platform](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Platform) `Platform.script` and `Platform.packageRoot` properties.

But when the script is running with `$ pub run tool/mytool`, the correct way to load data should be:

- detect that the script is running from the pub run command
- find the pub server host
- load data from this server, because there could be pub transformers and we can't load data directly from the file system.

And even if I want to load data directly from the file system, when the script is running with `pub run`, `Platform.script` returns `/mytool` path.

So, the question is there any way to find that the script is running from `pub run` and how to find server host for the pub server?

Comment: "Is there any way to find that the script is running from pub run?".  Probably not. "How to find server host for the pub server?". If a some behavior is not documented you can find (temporary) solution only after  seeing of the source code of the "pub". The reliability of this approach is very low, but it all depends on that the what level of reliability you wish assign to your code.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that this is the right way, but when I am running script with `pub run`, `Package.script` actually returns `http://localhost:<port>/myscript.dart`. So, when the scheme is `http`, I can download using http client, and when it is a `file`, load from the file system.

Something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as ospath;

Future<List<int>> loadAsBytes(String path) {
  final script = Platform.script;
  final scheme = Platform.script.scheme;

  if (scheme.startsWith('http')) {
    return new HttpClient().getUrl(
        new Uri(
            scheme: script.scheme,
            host: script.host,
            port: script.port,
            path: 'packages/' + path)).then((req) {
      return req.close();
    }).then((response) {
      return response.fold(
          new BytesBuilder(),
          (b, d) => b..add(d)).then((builder) {
        return builder.takeBytes();
      });
    });

  } else if (scheme == 'file') {
    return new File(
        ospath.join(ospath.dirname(script.path), 'packages', path)).readAsBytes();
  }

  throw new Exception('...');
}
```

Comment: A good solution for a very bad case of life (`pub run`). I did not know about it. Now I will never use them (`pub run`).